# Pandas - get rid of NaNs based on column values

Tags: pandas

I need to get rid of NaNs here, consolidating my Dataframe based on my 'id' column, which has a fixed set of values, always.

```
          id                        home_5                         home_4  \
0      277.0                      21.231579                            NaN   
1      280.0                      20.689474                            NaN   
2      282.0                      16.152632                            NaN   
3      262.0                      16.026316                            NaN   
4      284.0                      12.642105                            NaN   
5      356.0                      12.163158                            NaN   
6      293.0                      11.715789                            NaN   
7      263.0                      11.452632                            NaN   
8      276.0                      11.405263                            NaN   
9      265.0                      10.505263                            NaN   
10     266.0                      10.363158                            NaN   
11     275.0                      10.010526                            NaN   
12     290.0                       9.242105                            NaN   
13     267.0                       9.063158                            NaN   
14     292.0                       8.600000                            NaN   
15     373.0                       8.357895                            NaN   
16     264.0                       7.584211                            NaN   
17     354.0                       6.989474                            NaN   
18     285.0                       6.168421                            NaN   
19     294.0                       5.784211                            NaN   
0      285.0                            NaN                      23.947368   
1      354.0                            NaN                      16.100000   
2      266.0                            NaN                      15.047368   
3      262.0                            NaN                      14.857895   
4      264.0                            NaN                      12.615789   
5      282.0                            NaN                      12.363158   
6      275.0                            NaN                      12.089474   
7      267.0                            NaN                      10.615789   
8      373.0                            NaN                      10.452632   
9      265.0                            NaN                       9.810526   
10     284.0                            NaN                       9.568421   
11     294.0                            NaN                       9.273684   
12     280.0                            NaN                       8.910526   
13     277.0                            NaN                       8.536842   
14     293.0                            NaN                       8.257895   
15     292.0                            NaN                       7.784211   
16     263.0                            NaN                       7.626316   
17     276.0                            NaN                       7.026316   
18     290.0                            NaN                       6.073684   
19     356.0                            NaN                       4.136842
```

Desired result:

```
          id                        home_5                         home_4  \
0      277.0                      21.231579                       8.536842    
1      280.0                      20.689474                       8.910526   
2      282.0                      16.152632                      12.363158   
3      262.0                      16.026316                      14.857895   
4      284.0                      12.642105                       9.568421   
5      356.0                      12.163158                       4.136842   
6      293.0                      11.715789                       8.257895   
7      263.0                      11.452632                       7.626316   
8      276.0                      11.405263                       7.026316   
9      265.0                      10.505263                       9.810526   
10     266.0                      10.363158                      15.047368   
11     275.0                      10.010526                      12.089474   
12     290.0                       9.242105                       6.073684   
13     267.0                       9.063158                      10.615789   
14     292.0                       8.600000                       7.784211   
15     373.0                       8.357895                      10.452632   
16     264.0                       7.584211                      12.615789   
17     354.0                       6.989474                      16.100000   
18     285.0                       6.168421                      23.947368   
19     294.0                       5.784211                       9.273684
```

---

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Did you already append one DataFrame under the other? Looks like it given the index. If so, better merge the two original DataFrames. If not, I suggest to split the DataFrame in 2, drop the NaN and merge it on `id`

Comment: Yes I have them appended. How would that merge look like?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on='id')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fix your df

```
out = df.groupby('id').first()
```

Comment: so simple. tks a lot